# Error AsyncGPUReadback - GfxBufferID is invalid

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use AsyncGPUReadback to get data from the meshes of a GameObject instantiated from a bundle, but I keep getting the following error

> AsyncGPUReadback - GfxBufferID is invalid

Couldn't find anything about it. Here is the code:

```
public static void Run(Mesh sourceMesh, System.Action<Mesh> callback)
{
    GraphicsBuffer sourceDataBuffer = sourceMesh.GetVertexBuffer(0);
    GraphicsBuffer sourceIndexBuffer = sourceMesh.GetIndexBuffer();

    var vertexCount = sourceDataBuffer.count;
    var indexCount = sourceIndexBuffer.count;

    byte[] sourceData = new byte[vertexCount * (sourceDataBuffer.stride / sizeof(byte))];
    byte[] sourceIndex = new byte[(int)(indexCount * ((float)sourceIndexBuffer.stride / sizeof(byte)))];

    UnityEngine.Rendering.AsyncGPUReadback.Request(sourceDataBuffer, result =>
    {
        ...
    });
}
```

Doesn't AsyncGPUReadback work with asset bundles? I also tried the non-async GetData, but it doesn't work as well - I don't return any errors but the data is empty.

Answer (score 1):

For those who might be having the same problem, setting the vertexBufferTarget from the source mesh to Raw stopped the error:

```
sourceMesh.vertexBufferTarget = GraphicsBuffer.Target.Raw;
```

The result I'm getting from the call is still not correct, but at least the error is gone.